# Pass mysql count to view codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

I was looking to count where there was data present only. so if there is a record with no 0 I do not want it to be counted.

```
function count()
  {
  $this->db->select('COUNT(id)');
  $this->db->from('projects');
  $this->db->where(array('id !=' => ''));
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result_array();
  }
```

Controller `$data ['total'] = $this->mymodel->count`;

View `echo $total`

Table structure

```
Proj_name    |   user Id
-----------------------------------
A.        |    1

B.        |    2

C.        |    2
```

Result should be

```
Proj_name    |   Total
```

Project by id

```
A     |   1
B    |    2
```

Comment: so where is **C** ??

Comment: C should return 0

Comment: C has value of 2. So how this possible ??

Comment: I edited the table

Comment: You cant remove **C** if its dynamic data. Specify the reason of removing c

Comment: I need to count user project id's please check the table my bad